# How to map Zend_Db_Table_Row object to Zend_Form_Element_Select options (optial way)

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-db

How would You populate Zend_Form_Element_Select with options direct from Zend_Db_Table_Row?

For instance:

```
    $select = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('user_id', array(
        'required'  => true
        ));

    // fetching users for select
    $userTable = new User_Model_DbTable_User();
    $users = $userTable->fetchAll();
    $select->addMultiOptions($users->toArray());
```

But this will not work to good. Let say I want to have object id as a option value and some object property as an select label.

I know I can run foreach thourgh the rowset and construct an array of options but maybe there is some kind of map function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any *map* function you create would be iterating the rowset so you might as well simply do that, eg

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $select->addMultiOption($user->id, $user->someObjectProperty);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you also may consider tailoring a model method to return exactly the array you want use.
Perhaps something similar to:

```
public function fetchSelectList() {
        $resultSet = $this->fetchAll();
        $entries = array();
        foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
            $entry['id'] = $row->id;
            $entry['name'] = $row->name;

            $entries[] = $entry;
        }
        return $entries;
    }
```